# Reward questions that come up in search engine results?

Tags: discussion, reputation, search

A suggestion, which might be unworkable... track in some way when questions are found in search engines or SE search. For external search engines I suppose you can only track when someone comes to the question *from* the search-results page?

My thinking is this would reward questions which are titled in a search-friendly way.

Discuss?

Comment: For what it’s worth, I think that [Popular Question badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/26/popular-question) already achieves what you describe to some degree.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how rewarding people for using common keywords over relevant keywords is going to help.

Comment: Well then that's easily addressed using standard SEO stuff... only count page views where they don't leave within 5s or something.

Answer (score 4):

There are already badges for questions with a certain number of views, if you manage to ask a very popular question you get a shiny gold badge.

Answer (score 0):

We should reward people for simply viewing a number of questions displayed in a search - even if it's only from the possible duplicate title list for a new question and the search field on SO pages.  I'd like to see a small reputation bonus but a badge might work, too.

This would work like the bonus/badge you get for reviewing the FAQ.  Just getting some users used to looking at possible dups via search would have an overall positive effect of the number of actual dup questions asked.

I think 10 rep and a badge might not sound like much to us, but to someone just starting out on SO it might be enough to get them in the habit of searching more.